# Converting value object into correct RegistryValueKind

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to edit a value inside the registry using this line in my code:

```
dontAskOptions.SetValue("IDS_WARN_GENERAL_WINXP_EOL", 0xffffffff, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

The program throw an error saying that "the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted". I am guessing the 0xffffffff is not a DWord value. How do I correctly convert this?

Comment: Yeah, that .NET framework code does not win any prizes.  It blatantly assumes you passed an *int* even though you specified DWord.  You can use -1 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use a signed int. You can convert it using an [unchecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) cast

```
dontAskOptions.SetValue(
    "IDS_WARN_GENERAL_WINXP_EOL", 
    unchecked((int) 0xffffffff), 
    RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```